# sudo без пароля в программе на СИ

Tags: linux, c, sudo

Вопрос касается только языка СИ, только ОС Линукс.

Суть задачи. 
Моя основная программа запускается с sudo, запрашивается пароль и идет выполнение. Далее уже в самой этой программе выполняются вызовы к различным внешним программам с использованием sudo (например, "sudo rm ..."). Поскольку время действия сессии sudo ограничено, первые несколько вызовов sudo из программы выполняются нормально. Но потом, когда время сессии заканчивается (а моя программа работает в течение нескольких часов), команды на выполнение внешних программ с sudo выполняться перестают.
Примечание. Запуск внешних программ изнутри моей делается с помощью popen(...).

Что делалось для решения проблемы: 
а) устанавливался большой timestamp_timeout; 
б) основная программа запускалась после ввода sudo -s

Проблема не была решена. Видимо, запуск внешних программ изнутри моей основной программы рассматривается не как продолжение сессии sudo основной программы. Полностью отменять запрос пароля sudo для текущего пользователя я не хочу. Требуется решение, которое позволит запускать внешние программы изнутри моей основной программы в не зависимости от времени действия сессии sudo. Либо как запускать внешние программы с одновременной передачей пароля sudo.

Заранее благодарю за конструктивные ответы.

Comment: `sudo ... | <password>` Работает? нет?

Comment: `sudo myprogram` и не нужно заниматься странным

Comment: Уважаемые Данил и Alexey Ten, sudo | pass не работает в bash на debian. Насчет запуска основной программы с sudo я уже написал в самом вопросе. Это не решение

Comment: Про debian вы не говорили. Уточните свой вопрос.

Comment: Вы сами написали `Моя основная программа запускается с sudo`, в каком смысле это не решение? для чего из программы Вы вызываете заново sudo, когда у программы и так есть root права

Comment: Я ничего не говорил про | pass. Я говорил, что если вашей программе нужны права рута, то её надо запускать с правами рута и не пихать внутрь программы sudo

Comment: У вас точно программа на C? По описанию похоже на bash внутри обёртки на C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас явно какой-то неправильный воркфлоу. Но для такого неправильного воркфлоу есть решение. `sudo -S program <<<"YourPassWord"` или `echo "YourPassWord"|sudo -S program`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой сложный `prompt`.

Comment: Уважаемый Oxyd, Ваше решение работает и оно точно отвечает именно на поставленный мною вопрос. Благодарю Вас за помощь.

Comment: @dita137 Не забудьте отметить ответ решением! ;-)

Comment: @mkkik Да обычный. Из поставки oh-my-zsh.

Answer (score 5):

если программа запущена с root правами, то они останутся до ее завершения, внутри нее не нужно использовать sudo

Comment: В ubuntu всё не так просто. Там всегда нужен sudo.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, блин, я не знаю как подтвердить свои слова, но софт который я пишу работает, под десятком вариаций debian включая ubuntu и "военную" астру, так же есть qnx и другие posix системы, везде это работает одинаково

Comment: В ubuntu нет `root` пользователя. Есть группа `sudo`. Если ты в группе `sudo` пароль обязательно спросят ещё раз.

Comment: wut? это в какой posix системе нет root? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7m9U.png

Comment: http://blog.sedicomm.com/2018/03/29/kak-vklyuchit-otklyuchit-vhod-root-v-ubuntu/

Comment: @AlexGlebe, открою для тебя "секрет" но разрешение на вход под root ни как не связано с наличием этого дефолтного пользователя в **любой** posix системы

Comment: Точно так же как и наличие root прав не связано с наличием в /etc/pssswd пользователя c именем root

Comment: @Arenoros в ubuntu есть root. во первых все приложения системные запускаются от этого пользователя, во вторых чтобы зайти под root, надо написать `sudo su`

Comment: @xverizex, а мне то ты зачем об этом пишешь?)) я то в курсе

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo visudo
Меняем %sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
на %sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Получаем выполнение sudo от имени пользователя члена группы `sudo` без ввода пароля

Answer (score 0):

Может вместо `sudo` в popen переставлять **uid** через `setuid`, `setreuid`, `setresuid` или `setfsuid` (https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/seteuid.2.en)

Также чтоб не запскать программу под sudo поставить разрешение на бинарный файл через [Capabilities](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Capabilities)

```
setcap CAP_SETUID ./program
```

или

```
chown root ./program
chmod u+s ./program
```